# Export multiple (specific) worksheets to CSV files in a specified directory

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, csv

I'm new to VBA. I'm trying to do the following but the code isn't quite working as expected.

1. Export/Copy particular sheets in the workbook (any sheet name that contains "Upload") to a particular file directory.
2. I don't want these worksheet names to change nor the workbook name to change.
3. The file-name is consistent for each worksheet, so it would be okay to replace the files in the directory whenever I run the macro. Its okay to have a dialog box that asks if I'm sure I want to replace each of the files.
4. I don't want the newly created CSVs or any other file to open.

   ```
   Sub COPYSelectedSheetsToCSV()
   '
   '

   Sheets("Moo Upload").Select  
   Sheets("Moo Upload").Name = "Moo Upload"  
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/reginaho/Desktop/Upload/Moo Upload.csv", _  
   FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False  
   Sheets("Dodo Upload").Select  
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/reginaho/Desktop/Upload/Dodo Upload.csv", _  
   FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False  
   Sheets("Lulu Upload").Select  
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/reginaho/Desktop/Upload/Lulu Upload.csv", _  
   FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False  
   Sheets("Ahhh Upload").Select  
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/reginaho/Desktop/Upload/Ahhh Upload.csv", _  
   FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False  

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub COPYSelectedSheetsToCSV()

    Const FLDR  As String = "/Users/reginaho/Desktop/Upload/"
    Const ASK_  As Boolean = True

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = ASK_
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(LCase(ws.Name), "upload") > 0 Then ws.SaveAs FLDR & ws.Name, xlCSV
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not ASK_
End Sub
```